# redux-saga, call function on network complete?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'd like to call a component's function when network fetch completes.

```
function callRestApi({config, schema}) {
   return axios(config).then((response) => {

     if (schema) {
       var data = normalize_json(response.data, schema)
       response.entities = data.entities
     }

     return response
   })
 }

 function* fetchEventList(action) {
   try {
     const response = yield call(callRestApi, action.payload);
     // here I want to call a component's method if possible
     yield put({type: action.response.action_type_success, response});
   } catch (e) {
   }
 }
```

I can think of two ways to do this, and wonder if one is prefered over another or if there's a better way?

- method1:
  I include the component in the action payload so that I can call the method
- method2:
  on action.response.action_type_success, change redux state.
  Then, component's `componentWillReceiveProps` compare if the state variable changed and calls the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second. You are using redux-saga to handle side effects, so keep it that way. You could add a callback to the action as method1 but I wouldn't mix concepts.

If you update the store on success, it will re-render the component and as you said you could check the newly updated prop in **componentWillReceiveProps** and trigger the function, however, check nextProps instead of this.props (but I bet you already know that).

This way everything flows one way, no callback hell :) + you can easily test the component just by passing a prop.

Although it's not a bad pattern per se, passing callbacks would be bi-directional flow, which breaks the first rule of flux: Unidirectional flow.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, why does the 1st method cause bi-drectional flow?

Comment: So in flux, it goes like this: View -> Action -> Dispatcher -> Store -> View
if you pass a callback, it goes View <-> Action -> Dispatcher because it is breaking that one directional flow. Take a look here, and I think you'll properly understand it: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-concepts

Comment: Sorry I meant bi-directional flow (not data flow)

Comment: Thanks I understand what it is, although doc doesn't say why it's important.

Comment: Perhaps this sheds more light: https://hashnode.com/post/why-does-react-emphasize-on-unidirectional-data-flow-and-flux-architecture-ciibz8ej600n2j3xtxgc0n1f0